# light switch conversion 3 gang to 1 gang

Tags: switch, wifi

I have a three gang box, dimmable, switch, switch.  I want to use a wifi capable switch, but it comes with all three switches in a single gang switch.  How do you use the existing 3 gang box with only one gang switch now?

Comment: more specifically, a coverplate to make it look right.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is to install blanks into the unneeded openings, they are commercially available:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Get a switch plate that has 2 blank spaces in it, like [this one](https://www.kyleswitchplates.com/1-gfci-decora-rocker-2-blank-combination-switch-covers-white/) (link for illustration only, not a recommendation):

[image: switch cover]